# Selecting a specific input and adding an event to it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm experiencing an frustrating problem. 
I want to add an on-click event on an dynamically added input but I've been struggling with that for some time.

To show some code, here is my initial view

```
<div class="js-item-list"></div>
```

The user can then dynamically add data, this div is then populated for example like this (with initial divs)

```
<div class="js-item-list">
  <div class="js-service-list-item>
    <table>
      <tr>
       <td>Something</td>
       <td><input type="text" class="js-consumption"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="js-service-list-item>
    <table>
      <tr>
       <td>Something</td>
       <td><input type="text" class="js-consumption"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  ... and so on ...
</div>
```

I want to add an on-click event with jQuery to all the inputs so that when the users clicks on the input, all of the content of that specific input box would be selected. But I have no idea how to so all suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thanx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the jQuery's event delegate function may resolve your problem, try this :

```
$(".js-item-list").on("click" , "input.js-consumption" , function(){
    var domInput = this ;
    var $input = $(this) ;
    var value =  $input.val();
    // to do
});
```

Comment: sadly it' doesnt.. I have already tried something like that but without any success. I try and add an alert in the code to see if something happens, but nothing ever happens..

Comment: Accepting this answer as the most descriptive. 
As for my problem, it was resolved when I wrote this code outside of one of my functions

Answer (score 2):

You can use delegate method for newly added or future elements

[refrence](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

```
 $('.js-item-list').delegate('input', 'click', function(e) {
     //some code here
 })
```

or for newer version >1.7 of jquery you should use .on()

> As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method

```
$('.js-item-list').on('input', 'click', function(e) {
         //some code here
     })
```

Comment: It should be noted that `.delegate()`has been officially delegated. Instead, use `.on()`, i.e. `$('.js-item-list').on('click', 'input', function(e) { ...}`

Comment: Agree with Terry that  .on()  should be used. And this answer with .delegate() sadly isn't working :/

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jquery .on function, which work on dynamically added html element.

```
$(".js-item-list").on( "click", ".js-consumption" ,function() {
     alert( $( this ).val() );
});
```

**.js-item-list** is the selector class which is not change dynamically only inner element of this will be change.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have some button that the user clicks to add another "Something". I'm also assuming you have somewhere in your JS code `$(".js-service-list-item").onclick(someAction)`.

That initial JS code only applies to the elements with that class that exist **at the time it is run**. This means every time they add an element to the list, you need to reapply that onclick method.

So what I would do is move that `$(".js-service-list-item").onclick(someAction)` code into the onclick function you have for the button that adds these service-list-items. That way each time you create a new element, you'll also register the onclick event with it